# Which Java method gives me the better performance and why

Tags: java, performance, integer, int

I have two  method Test and Test1, first return int and second Integer with the value 1, which one is better as far as performance is under consideration.

```
public static int Test(){
        return new Integer(1);
    }


public static Integer Test1(){
        return 1;
    }
```

**Edit:** Also let me know the memory consumption in both the cases.

Comment: You can also gather these performance statistics yourself.

Comment: How, do you know?

Comment: Who cares?  This is a worthless nano-optimization.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Sorry, but nothing is worthless if we talk about the performance. Let say if you have such kind of 1000 methods, will you still no worry about what to use and why?

Comment: second method will be more master.

Comment: @NishantVerma If I would have 1000 methods that looks like this, then I would have a major design flaw and therefore a much bigger problem.

Comment: Create two applications, one that calls the first method a 1000(... more zeroes means more data to perform statistics on) and the other calls the second method the same number of times. Run these programs in a "similar" environment and compare things as completion time, memory usage and whatever else strikes your fancy. For more details, you should look into literature on performance testing (no references from the top of my head, sorry).

Comment: as long as the int is smaller than the integer cache Test1 will be slightly faster but more importantly predictable. Test will have unpredictable result as you create object on the heap and any allocation/gc will dominate the execution time. Source: http://pastebin.com/faNA869t

Answer (score 3):

The first method will not use the `IntegerCache` (available for `Integer` values between -128 and 127), so if you are calling it a large number of times it will be less efficient, since each call would create a new instance of `Integer`, that would be immediately eligible for garbage collection (since the first method returns a primitive, not a reference to the created `Integer`).

The second method will always return the same instance of the `Integer` class (thanks to the `IntegerCache`), which means less instantiation work and less garbage collector work. Therefore it's more efficient.
`return Integer.valueOf(1);` would also give you the same benefits as the second method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the **second method** will give you the better performance, because -

You are returning an `int` which will converted to `Integer` by wrapping.

And in the **first method** - 
**1.** you are generation an Integer from an `int`
**2.** then the `Integer` is again converted to `int` before retuning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long timeFirst = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int a = Test();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        //int a=Test();
        a += i;
    }
    long seconfFirst = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time " + (seconfFirst - timeFirst));
    long timeFirst1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Integer b=Test1();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        //Integer b = Test1();
        b += i;
    }
    long seconfFirst1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("timesecond" + (seconfFirst1 - timeFirst1));
}

public static int Test() {
    return new Integer(1);
}


public static Integer Test1() {
    return 1;
}
```

How do you use these method?
If you use these methods by this way, you can see the performance. The first method will give you better performance.

Output:

> time 6
>   timesecond32,
>   time 11
>   timesecond38,
>   time 8
>   timesecond27,
>   time 7
>   timesecond37

Comment: ... now try inverting which one you tested first and see again who's faster. also you are invoking the test methods only once, how does this benchmark do anything?

Comment: this benchmarking is between primitive and instances.you can use Test methods other scenario.And tested first is not important,again timesecond is bigger than time.

Comment: test order is important, java has a huge warm up time